# Hide HTML content when lightbox opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I have been messing around with the lightbox implementation found here

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg

And am struggling somewhat with the lightbox overlapping the menu and header on my page - i was wondering if it is possible to hide this content when the lightbox is seleted and reshow it again when it is not.

My code for this is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>About</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/tmStickUp.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
<script>

 $(window).load(function(){
  $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
 });
</script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
</style>
<body>

  <div class="main">
  <div class="ricki">
    <header>
      <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12">
          <h1 class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">SWAGGA dance academy</a>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <section id="stuck_container">
      <!--==============================
                  Stuck menu
      =================================-->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_12">
              <div class="navigation ">
                <nav>
                  <ul class="sf-menu">
                   <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
                   <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
                   <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                   <li class="current"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </header>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(6)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(7)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(8)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">6 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">7 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">8 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(7)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(8)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}

function hideHtmlOnClickOfLightbox(){

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxBUZ.jpg

Comment: I don´t completely understand what you want, the lightbox is overlapping your header and menu, but you want to hide the lightbox section that is overlapping this two elements of your page, right?

Comment: I want to hide the html content (links in the header and the header itself) else it overlays the image when the light box opens

Comment: The code provided for you this is not happening, look at this demo: http://output.jsbin.com/jadipexiro

Comment: I added a screenshot to my original post